# How padding in huggingface tokenizer works?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I tried following tokenization example:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_TYPE, do_lower_case=True)
sent = "I hate this. Not that.",        
_tokenized = tokenizer(sent, padding=True, max_length=20, truncation=True)
print(_tknzr.decode(_tokenized['input_ids'][0]))
print(len(_tokenized['input_ids'][0]))
```

The output was:

```
[CLS] i hate this. not that. [SEP]
9
```

Notice the parameter to `tokenizer`: `max_length=20`. How can I make Bert tokenizer to append 11 `[PAD]` tokens to this sentence to make it total `20`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One should set `padding="max_length"`:

```
_tokenized = tokenizer(sent, padding="max_length", max_length=20, truncation=True)
```

Comment: padding is added in the beginning or the end?

Comment: @NathanB: By default they're added at the end as `tokenizer.padding_side` is set to `right`. You can change that to `left` if you want padding at the start.